# Yield inside with block keep open postgres connection

Tags: python, generator, psycopg2

When `yield`ing from the below generator, is the postgres connection kept active or does the `yield` need to be less indented such that a new connection is made on every `next()`?

```
def getData(start, end):
    with psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='user' host='localhost' password='password'") as conn:
        time = start
        while time<end:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(query.format(start, time))
                data = cur.fetchall()
            time += one_week
            yield data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the context manager is kept active. `yield` *pauses* the function, nothing is exited.

`yield` doesn't alter the order of execution inside a function. The function is merely 'paused', frozen at the point where the `yield` expression has executed and produced a value. When the generator is later on resumed (by calling `__next__` on the iterator), the function continues at that point again. A `with` statement `__exit__` method can't be called when a generator is paused, so the context manager *can't* be exited until the generator is resumed, anyway.

You can see this happen if you create a simple context manager with the [`@contextmanager` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) (itself relying on a generator for the implementation!):

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def loud_contextmanager():
    print("Context entered!")
    try:
        yield "value to bind the 'as' target to"
    finally:
        exc_info = sys.exc_info()
        if exc_info:
            print("Context exited with an exception!", exc_info)
        else:
            print("Context exited!")

def generator_stages():
    yield "First yield, outside of a context manage"
    with loud_contextmanager() as cm_as_value:
        yield f"Inside of the with block, received {cm_as_value}"
    yield "Outside of with block, last yield"
```

And when you pull values from the generator to print, you'll see this:

```
>>> gen = generator_stages()
>>> print(next(gen))
First yield, outside of a context manage
>>> print(next(gen))
Context entered!
Inside of the with block, received value to bind the 'as' target to
>>> print(next(gen))
Context exited with an exception! (None, None, None)
Outside of with block, last yield
>>> next(gen, "generator was done")
'generator was done'
```

Note that the context is not exited until we retrieve the 3rd value! After the second `next()` call the code is paused at a point inside of the `with` block, and only when unpaused can the context be exited, and the `finally` suite of the `loud_contextmanager()` function can be run.